# I want to store a character string in block of memory space created by malloc and then modify the same space to store a much larger string

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 

int
main()
{ 

int n,i;

printf("Enter the size or the number of chracters that you want to enter inside the string.\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

char *p = (char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
if(p==NULL)
 {
 printf("Memory allocation fails..");
 exit(0);
 }
 
puts("Enter string");
for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
scanf("%c",p+i);

*(p+i)= '\0';

printf("String entered %s",p);

fflush(stdin);

printf("\nEnter new size\n");
scanf(" %d",&n); 

p = realloc(p,(n+1)*sizeof(char));

puts("Enter new string");
scanf("%d", &n);

 for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
 scanf("%c",p+i);
 
 *(p+i)= '\0'; 
 
 printf("New string \n%s",p);
 
 free(p);
 
return 0;
}
```

I used an online compiler (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler).

The question that I want to ask. When I enter more elements than the size that I initialized for the string during runtime. It does not take the next input and prints the result. And when I enter less than the size limit, it does not go to the next part. Instead, it takes multiple inputs to move towards the next part and print the results.

When I enter string within the size limit.

[image]

When I enter string more than the size limit.

[image]

When I try to enter string less than the size limit.
[image]

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `*(p+i)= '\0';` is bad when `i == n+1`.  Use `for(i=0;i<(n /* +1 */);i++)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop

```
for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
    scanf("%c",p+i);
```

will keep running until you've entered all characters. That's why you need to write `a` until the array is filled in the last screenshot. If you want the line to be read when enter is pressed you can use [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Regarding the other screenshots, as per C standard, it is undefined behavior to use fflush(stdin). Thats why the input buffer doesn't get flushed. You can use

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); //Discard
```

to flush stdin